# Java - Can't access local jframe inside another class

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Hello world,  I am kinda new to java and I have a problem, I am trying to access a local jframe in a different class e.g

```
        Public class Mine extends JFrame {

           public Mine() {
               setSize(200,200);
               setTitle("Mine");
               setVisible("true");

               JButton b = new JButton("Open");
               b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

               JFrame fine = new JFrame("How are You");
               fine.sizeSize(200,200);
               fine.setVisible(true);
               }
               )};

           }
        }
```

Now I am trying to access the local JFrame  which is :

```
      JFrame fine = new JFrame("How are you");
```

Please I this is not good code, all I am asking is that is there a way I can access a local JFrame in another class constructor like

Comment: `fine` is scoped to that constructor. Once that constructor completes, as far as you are concerned, `fine` doesn't exist. How exactly do you plan to access it?

Comment: Why do you need to create another JFrame? JFrames are top level containers and unless you want an entirely separate window, you should use something that's not a top-level container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little difficult to ascertain what you're attempting here, or why you would want to do it, but if you want to access that JFrame fine from a different class, you should declare it as an instance variable and create an accessor method for it:

```
Public class Mine extends JFrame {

    private JFrame fine;

    public Mine() {
        ...
        ...
        fine = new JFrame("How are You");
        ... 
        ...
   }

   public JFrame getFine() {
       return fine;
   }
```

Comment: At first didn't understand but two years down i got it even more advanced!!!!. Thank you!!